# React to incoming files in a directory on HP-UX

Tags: shell-script, files, monitoring, hp-ux

How can I achieve  this logic using a script:

Monitor new incoming files in a directory. If files are not received in the directory for 3 hours or if  the received file is empty
then do something. File names are dynamically generated.

How can I put this in a script?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [HP-UX](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/System-Administration/Inotify/td-p/4623027#.VFxPrVRdX0M) does not have anything like FAM/FSEvent/inotify to react to incoming files. This leaves polling as the only solution.

Here's a proof-of-concept script that triggers every minute and calls the `process` program on each new file (put whatever you want in that program) then moves the file to a different directory. Moving the file to a different directory is done to avoid race conditions that would lead to a file being skipped or processed multiple times; if you really need the files to stay in the same directory, maintain a list of already-processed files instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh93
last_SECONDS=0
while sleep 60; do
  new_files=$(find INCOMING -exec process {} \; -exec mv {} PROCESSED \; -print)
  if [[ -n $new_files ]]; then
    last_SECONDS=$SECONDS
  elif ((SECONDS - last_SECONDS >= 3600 * 3)); then
    echo "More than 3 hours without a new file"
  fi
done
```